# DRF Custom Serializer Error Fomat

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django/ Django Rest Framework. 
I want custom message i.e "staus" along with custom error message.
Error message can be.

1. Email not found
2. Wrong password

**Required Output format**

```
#status_code 200 ok
{
  "status":"failure",
  "status_message":"Email not found"
}
```

**View.py**

```
class UserLogin(APIView):
  permissions_class = [AllowAny]
  serializer_class=UserLoginSerailizer

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     mydata = request.data
     serializer=UserLoginSerailizer(data=mydata)
     if serializer.is_valid(): 
        new_data=serializer.data
        return Response({"status":"success","message":"success","result":new_data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
     return Response({"status":"failure","message":serializer.errors},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class UserLoginSerailizer(ModelSerializer):
  email_id=EmailField(required=True)
  password=CharField(required=True,error_messages={'required':'Password field is required.'})
  jwt_token=CharField(allow_blank=True,read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model=User
    fields = [
        'email_id',
        'password',
        'jwt_token',
    ]
    extra_kwargs ={"password":{"write_only":True}}

  def validate(self,data):
    user_obj=None
    email_id=data.get("email_id")
    password=data["password"]
    user=User.objects.filter(email=email_id)

    if user.exists():
        user_obj =user.first()
    else:
        raise ValidationError({"error_message":"Email not found"})

    if user_obj:
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError({"error_message":"Wrong password"})

    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user_obj)

    data["jwt_token"]=jwt_encode_handler(payload)

    return data
```

**Current Output**

```
 {
  "status": "failure",
  "status_message": {
    "error_message": [
        "Email not found"
    ]
    }
 }
```

I tried this other way customizing ValidationError but instead of giving 200 status code it used to give 400 bad request and i was not able to add custom message also. i am not sure what the best way to achieve this so i tried like this. Please let me what the best way to achieve my requirement

Comment: this is extremely bad practice, because how are you to know when a request has errored without checking the text?  the status code lets you check by number range easily and go from there.  In addition, most JS ajax libraries will use the status code to throw errors which are caught in the promises.  tl;dr please do not do this.

Comment: I know its very bad practice of doing code. But this was client requirement he want me to send 200 status code for error so. yeah sometime we have to change code as per client requirement,

Comment: does the client know this is bad practice?  have you explained the reason why?

Comment: yes ofcourse. he is Android developer by profession.

Comment: i am backend developer my job is creating REST API for mobile apps and backend admin

Comment: well, good luck.  for me, this is a major red flag regarding your client's competency as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a utility function that just takes some parameters and returns a message in the format you need.

example..

```
  def Message(status, message):
    return {"status":status,"status_message":message}
```

So from now on when you need to return messages you just call the function

```
return Response(Message("failure", "Email not found"),status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

You can obviously add a lot more to this function, other parameters that will return data etc.. but that will be up to you.

Comment: iits giving me output like `{
    "status": "failure2",
    "status_message": {
        "status_message": [
            "Email not found"
        ]
    }
}` and this is similar what i am getting currently.

Comment: i am looking for "status_message":"Email not found"

Answer (score 0):

I had added this custom_validation function in serializer.py

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class custom_ValidationError(APIException):
 status_code = 200
```

changed in code

```
raise ValidationError({"status_message":"Email not found"})
```

to

```
raise custom_ValidationError({"status":"failure","status_message":"Email not found"})
```

Now i am getting the desired output with 200 status_code

```
{
 "status":"failure",
 "status_message":"Email not found"
}
```